# Returning a list of indexes of the smallest value in a multidimensional list

Tags: python

This should be simple enough.

I have a multidimensional list of integers, for example:

```
a = [[5,5,5,4,6],[3,2,6,6,5],[7,2,2,5,6]]
```

I need a way to return a list of indexes of the positions with lowest number.  In this example, it would be the indexes corresponding to the value 2, or ((1,1),(2,1),(2,2)).

I'm thinking a list comprehension method, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What did you try for yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use list comprehension:

```
>>> a = [[5,5,5,4,6],[3,2,6,6,5],[7,2,2,5,6]]

>>> minn = min(min(x) for x in a) #find the min value

>>> [(i,j) for i,x in enumerate(a) for j,y in enumerate(x) if y==minn]
[(1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = [[5,5,5,4,6],[3,2,6,6,5],[7,2,2,5,6]]
>>> res = []
>>> smallest = float('inf')
>>> for i, x in enumerate(a):
        for j, y in enumerate(x):
            if y < smallest:
                smallest = y
                res = [(i, j)]
            elif y == smallest:
                res.append((i, j))


>>> res
[(1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I won't give you the quick solution since this is a simple programming excersise, but I will say that two nested `for` loops and a variable tracking minimum and its position are enough. To be more Pythonic, you may try to put `enumerate` at work.

Answer (score 0):

```
aa = [[5,5,5,4,6],[3,2,6,6,5],[7,2,2,5,6]]    
min_ = min(i for a in aa for i in a)
[(i,j) for i,a in enumerate(aa) for j,b in enumerate(a) if b == min_]

[(1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```